# Getting error while fetching records from execute_string method using python and snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am getting error while fetching records from execute_string method.

**`Code`**

```
query_string = select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position FROM db.information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'Schema' AND table_name = 'TABLE_CDC' and table_name not like '%_STG_LOAD' and table_name not like '%_STG_TABLE' and table_name not like '%\\_EXT' and table_name not like 'RECON%' and column_name not in ('RECORD_DELETE_IND', 'DATA_LOAD_SOURCE', 'DATA_UPDATE_SOURCE', 'DATA_LOAD_TIME', 'RECORD_MD5', 'SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID', 'DATA_UPDATE_TIME') order by table_name, ordinal_position;
```

**`Result`**

```
Row  TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  ORDINAL_POSITION
1    TABLE_CDC   DEVICE        1
2    TABLE_CDC   AGE           2
3    TABLE_CDC   SEX           3

col_cursor_list = conn.execute_string(query_string)
for col_cursor in col_cursor_list:
    df = pd.DataFrame(col_cursor.fetchall())
    csv_column_name = ','.join(df[1])
```

**Error**

```
Empty DataFrame
```

**Expected output**

```
DF should have the rows but It returned empty dataframe.
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
query1 = """
select table_name, column_name, ordinal_position FROM db.information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'PUBLIC' AND table_name = 'CITIBIKE_TRIPS' order by table_name, ordinal_position;
"""
rs = ctx.execute_string(query1)
for c in rs:
    df = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall())
    csv_col_name = ','.join(df[1])
print(csv_col_name)
```

I get back:

```
RIDE_ID,RIDEABLE_TYPE,STARTED_AT,ENDED_AT,START_STATION_NAME,START_STATION_ID,END_STATION_NAME,END_STATION_ID,START_LAT,START_LNG,END_LAT,END_LNG,MEMBER_CASUAL
```

So this doesn't look to be a Snowflake Python connector issue. Maybe post a full sample of your script so we can test it.
Also are you sure the result of the query is not empty?

Comment: Yes Result of the query is not empty. I have executed the script in snowflake and got the result.

Comment: I am suspecting this could be role issue. As I am using role from secret and might be doesn't have permission to execute the query.